# Mythological/godlike name for a manager

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I wonder if there's a term, possibly a name, relating to a god, mythological creature or such, that is used in English to describe a person, software or organization that manages cases, runs errands and takes care of issue resolutions.

For instance, I've hear people call a guy by the name of [Argus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argus_Panoptes) and for a very long time I believed that it was his actual name. Turns out, they only meant that the person in question keeps an eye on all the details, is never ambushed and knows what's going on around in the office.

There's a software related solution called [Kerberos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerberus), which refers to the doggie watching at the door of a rather hot place. The software is used for security and protection in the digital environment.

I'd like to know if there's anything equivalent (possibly extremely rarely used in, or at the very least applicable to, English language) for a case managing and/or issue resolution instance, person or software.

Comment: I'd have expected this question on ELU, rather than here...?

Comment: @Stephie Are you referring to the other English language related site in the network? I got the impression lately that one gets bashed more heavily lately there if a question is isn't sophisticated enough, according to their quite rather acquired taste. Personally I fell that they take the lower limit of acceptable questions too high but I prefer not to contribute to an (yet another and equally pointless) infected discussion.

Comment: @Stephie - Some questions are obvious ELL questions, some are obvious ELU questions, and some could find a comfortable home in either place. In that last case, I think it's best to let the O.P. ask where they are most comfortable asking. That said, this _is_ a hard question – but I don't regard that as a bad thing. This site could use some posers and stumpers every once in a while.

Comment: @J.R. Am I appearing to be a poser? Or did I regrettably missed your point? Several times I've been nagged on (on occasion, not very politely) to keep my this-and-that-way-too-basic questions out of the sophisticated sphere. Finally, instead of engaging in what, IM-not-so-HO, is just a sad attempt to feel better by stamping on others, I decided to display some maturity and as at the referred site. Boom - suddenly, it's **too hard** (an opinion I fully agree with). I'm confused as to where ask questions now...   :D

Comment: Konrad, you are *very welcome* to ask questions here, even callenging ones. I was just surprised, because we get a lot of very basic questions here. I can relate to *some* people over as ELU being a rather snobbish lot - I had my share of bashing, too. I ment no offense, so sorry if my message rubbed the wrong way.

Comment: @Konrad - You are not the poser; the question is. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I meant [poser](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/poser) in the sense of "a very difficult question." I assure you, my comment was meant to be 100% complimentary, though it's easy to see how you might have been confused.

Comment: I don't know that such a term is generally used this way; if so, you may get only speculative answers. As such, I am not sure that your research skills are any less able than that of native speakers to attempt to locate an appropriate word.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about literary or religious personae,  not about the use of the English language.

Comment: @choster I'd claim that it's **precisely** about usage of English language, because I'm looking for a word that describes a certain properties or is associated with a certain perception of qualities. For instance - "*Achilletic*" has a certain connotation and it's related to the Greek dude but it **usage** is linguistical. Also - c.f. "*Freudian touch*" - it's not about Mr. Freud. It's about, probably, having sex with your mom. Or butt touching. (Kind of narrow spectrum on Sigmund, there.)

Comment: @J.R. Oh, got it. How nice, then. I'm a bike aficionado, you see, and in our sphere the term "*poser*" is rather vastly diminishing, because someone **posing** as a biker is the exact opposite of all the romanticized (positive) qualities that a true biker carries (whatever those might be). Of course - YMMVVV.

Comment: @Stephie Now that I read your comment, I realize that it can be interpreted as nosy and a bit hostile **but also** as appreciative and welcoming. Apparently I'm colored by the wrong type of replies I've received lately and so it reflected here. Please accept my apology. I should've interpreted your contribution as something positive **unless** evidently otherwise. :)

Comment: @choster - If someone is very bright, we can say, "He's an Einstein." If someone is chasing a fool's errand, we might call her _quixotic_. If a neighbor is annoyingly sanctimonious, I might describe him as _Pecksniffian_, and if he loves himself too much, he's a _narcissist_. These are all valid English words rooted in proper nouns. Now a non-native asks if a similar word exists to describe someone running a complex operation. Suppose such a word _was_ in everyday use; why not ask for it here? The question isn't any less valid just because one doesn't roll right off our collective tongues.

Comment: You could use one of the [Fates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fates) - maybe Lachesis or Atropos who measure and cut the thread of life. I'm not very familiar with the mythology of the fates in other cultures - there may be others that are closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I can think of is *wizard*. It's not a proper name like Argus, but it does denote a mythological profession. As [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/wizard) says:

> **wizard** (*n.*) a man in stories who has magic powers

but the second definition reads:

> **wizard** someone who is very good at something

I like the meaning listed in [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/wizard) even better:

> **wizard** (*n.*) a person who is outstandingly clever in some specified field; expert

The meaning listed in the [Online Slang Dictionary](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/wizard) seems even closer to what you are seeking:

> **wizard** (*noun*) used with a subject matter to refer to a person with deep, expert knowledge of that subject matter : *We're looking to hire a Unix wizard*.

---

If you're looking for a proper name, there's always **Hercules**, who was known for his twelve labors, and who gave us the word [*herculean*](http://www.onelook.com/?w=herculean&ls=a) to describe something that is tremendously arduous or difficult. Out of curiosity, I entered `software herculean task` into a [search engine](http://www.google.com/search?q=software%20herculean%20task), and found no small number of business articles, tech columns, and blogs, that mentioned things such as:

- [The Herculean task of upgrading a development language or environment](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/the-herculean-task-of-upgrading-a-development-language-or-environment/)
- the information needed to be successful in [the herculean task of securing your company with a modern SIEM](http://www.blackstratus.com/blog/deploying-siem-environment/)

With that in mind, it wouldn't be too much of a stretch to hang the nickname Hercules on someone who keeps a software organization running smoothly. (I've never heard that used, though, so I suppose it falls under the category of "possibly extremely rarely used".)

Comment: I'll consider *Hercules*. However, the name makes me associate to a person **actually carrying out** assigned tasks. I'm rather aiming at the person **running the show**, i.e. **assigning**, **creating** and **accepting** the tasks to be carried out. You might have given me a great lead here, after all. Hercules hasn't been running around sweating just for the fun of it. Someone made him. (+1 for the help-to-self-help)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the name of an ancient king.

If you want to be snarky, a possibility is:

- Herod, the [infamous](http://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Matthew-Chapter-2/) "pointy haired boss".

If you want to honor the manager, a possibility is:

- Cyrus (a.k.a. Koresh), the Persian who established a cosmopolitan empire under the rule of law.  He defeated the Assyrian empire, which had boasted of its looting.

Another possibility is a "messenger of the Gods":

- Iris
- Hermes
- Mercury

Answer (score 0):

The best nickname would probably be Zeus the highest god in Greek mythology.

Comment: How would you motivate it, please?

Comment: Zeus is described as [the most important deity of ancient Greece, the leader of the gods and the all-powerful overseer of earthly events and human destiny](http://www.mythencyclopedia.com/Wa-Z/Zeus.html#ixzz3PaHt7GA1)